# Using phoenix_html_simplified_helpers with a date

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a `user` model:

```
defmodule AddressBook.User do
  use AddressBook.Web, :model

  schema "users" do
    field :last_name, :string
    field :birthday, Ecto.Date
[...]
```

I want to use https://github.com/ikeikeikeike/phoenix_html_simplified_helpers to render `time_ago_in_words` for the `birthday`:

```
<%= time_ago_in_words user.birthday %> ago
```

But that results in this error:

[image: Screenshot of the error]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that package [does not support](https://github.com/ikeikeikeike/phoenix_html_simplified_helpers/blob/d73c6209774a6a29b4010979fd3385370a46cd86/lib/phoenix_html_simplified_helpers/time_ago_in_words.ex#L11-L88) `Ecto.Date`, only `Ecto.DateTime`, `Timex.DateTime`, or raw seconds offset. This should work:

```
<%= time_ago_in_words Ecto.DateTime.from_date(user.birthday) %> ago
```